# (Google-apps-script) How to select separate columns from a shared datatable for a bar chart

Tags: google-apps-script, bar-chart

I have searched for a clue to this for quite a while, and have not yet found a solution. What I am trying to do is use a shared datatable from a dashboard and select two columns from within the datatable to show in a bar chart. I have three other charts (pie charts) which share this same information.

I have two category filters set up to filter the information, and would like these filters shared with the bar chart.

My only solution so far has been the thought of creating a second datatable solely for the bar chart, but then I run into the problem of shared filters without adding secondary controls.

Is it possible to do nested .setColumns within the barChart? If possible, I would like to be able to utilize ranges [0,3] and [0,4].

Any help that you all can offer with this would be much appreciated. Code is below:

```
 function doGet() {
   var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AqAulwN3maXQdE1TanZFUlZ2NVR5UHMzRUlfWUM2dUE');
   var datasource = ss.getRangeByName("dashRange").getValues();
   Logger.log(datasource);
   var data = Charts.newDataTable()
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, datasource [0] [0])
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, datasource [0] [1])
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, datasource [0] [2])
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [3])
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [4])
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [5])
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [6])
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [7])
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [8])
       for (i=1;i<=datasource.length-1;i++){
         Logger.log(datasource [i]);
         data.addRow([datasource [i] [0], datasource [i] [1], datasource [i] [2], datasource [i] [3], datasource [i] [4], datasource [i] [5], datasource [i] [6], datasource [i] [7], datasource [i] [8]])
       };

   data.build();

   var stationFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
       .setFilterColumnLabel("Station")
       .build();

   var divisionFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
       .setFilterColumnLabel("Division")
       .build();

   var dayChart = Charts.newPieChart()
       .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
                              .setColumns([0,6]))
       .setTitle("Revenue Today")
       .build();

   var mtdChart = Charts.newPieChart()
       .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
                              .setColumns([0,7]))
       .setTitle("Revenue MTD")
       .build();

   var ytdChart = Charts.newPieChart()
       .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
                              .setColumns([0,8]))
       .setTitle("Revenue YTD")
       .build();

   var barChart = Charts.newBarChart()
       .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
                              .setColumns([0,4]))
       .setTitle("Utilization")
       .setRange(0,20)
       .build();

   var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
       .setDimensions(800, 500)
       .build();

   var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
       .setDataTable(data)
       .bind([stationFilter, divisionFilter], [dayChart, mtdChart, ytdChart, barChart, tableChart])
       .build();
   dashboard.add(uiApp.createVerticalPanel()
                 .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                      .add(divisionFilter).add(stationFilter)
                      .setSpacing(70))
                 .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                      .add(dayChart).add(mtdChart).add(ytdChart)
                      .setSpacing(10))
                 .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                      .add(barChart).add(tableChart)
                      .setSpacing(10)));
   uiApp.add(dashboard);
   return uiApp;
 }
```

[Edit]
Answered my own question. I simply had to extend the columns.

```
var barChart = Charts.newBarChart()
       .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
                              .setColumns([0,4,3]))
       .setColors(["green", "red"])
       .setStacked()
       .setTitle("Utilization")
       .setRange(0,20)
       .build();
```

Thanks folks. I will mark this as answered as soon as I am able to.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above...

I simply had to extend the columns:

```
var barChart = Charts.newBarChart()
       .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
                              .setColumns([0,4,3]))
       .setColors(["green", "red"])
       .setStacked()
       .setTitle("Utilization")
       .setRange(0,20)
       .build();
```

Sometimes it just takes a sounding board